# CSS only menu, click to disappear

Tags: css

I have a menu structured like this:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="drnav">
        <ul class="ulMenu">
            <li>
                <div class="menuHeader">My Home</div>
                <div class="menu-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="menuHeader">My Stuff</div>
                <div class="menu-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css is setup so that when you hover over a menuHeader element the menu-content element is displayed (i.e. display: inline).  This all works fine but what I want is that when you click one of the links in the list item elements within the menu-content that the menu (i.e. the parent menu-content element) disappears.  Of course I want to do this without any JavaScript.  I saw one example that used pointer-events but that restricts use to IE 11 and I'd like to support at least IE 10 if not 9 as well.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: How was `pointer-events` used in a useful way without JS changing values? Do you have that example? Where's your CSS?

Comment: pointer-events allowed mouse events to pass through to ancestor elements so that :focus would be available on those parent elements (which is kinda what I need to make the parent element disappear)

Comment: Ok, I think I might have a better way...

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's possible, but it's much ado about nothing (hard to use it in practice):

```css
.ulMenu .menu-content {
  display: none;
}
.ulMenu > li:hover .menu-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ulMenu > li .menu-content:target {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="drnav">
        <ul class="ulMenu">
            <li>
                <div class="menuHeader">My Home</div>
                <div class="menu-content" id="menuContent_1">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#menuContent_1">item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#menuContent_1">item3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="menuHeader">My Stuff</div>
                <div class="menu-content" id="menuContent_2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#menuContent_2">item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#menuContent_2">item5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides, once you close a menu the only way to reopen it is by opening another and hovering the initial one.

---

**Important note:**

I would like to point out having a `:hover` based menu is a huge disadvantage compared to having a `JavaScript` based menu. Because more than half of today's traffic is coming from touch devices (and you don't hover much on a touch-device, do you?) while only less than `1%` of traffic has `JavaScript` disabled.

So, could you perhaps explain why you ask for a pure CSS solution? The only practical use for pure CSS I had in past 8 years was for a payment gateway page, where JavaScript was strictly off. But, other than that?

I happen to know my way around CSS, but I was never keen on trying to transfer DOM manipulations to CSS, instead of leaving them for JavaScript. After all, that's what JavaScript is for. Use the right tool for the job. The job here is DOM manipulation. So use JavaScript.

---

Here's is the `input`/`label` solution I described in the comments. I realized they don't have to be checkboxes, I can use the `:focus` state to hide the menu contents. It's still buggy, in the sense that a click anywhere in the page is needed to make the `:hover` work again for the recently closed menu. But it's the closest you can get with `CSS` only or, at least, that's what I think.

```css
.menuHeader input:focus + label,
.menuHeader label {
  display: none;
}
.menuHeader:hover label
{
  display: inline-block;
}
input.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulMenu">
  <li>
    <div class="menuHeader">
      <div>My Home</div>
      <input id="menuContent_1" class="hidden" type="text" />
      <label class="menu-content" for="menuContent_1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#menuContent_1">item1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#menuContent_1">item2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuHeader">
      <div>My Stuff</div>
      <input id="menuContent_2" class="hidden" type="text" />
      <label class="menu-content" for="menuContent_2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#menuContent_2">item4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#menuContent_2">item5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Reason for pure CSS:  javascript = code => requires unit tests = (more work + more code to browser).  I don't consider this manipulating the DOM, just triggering/applying different classes when certain events happen.  CSS does this with events like hover, active, focus but no reliable handler for when an element is clicked.  The main problem is that I can't style an ancestor element based on the condition of a child element (which of course would kind of violate the "cascading" part of CSS).

Comment: You're wrong about "applying different classes". CSS does not apply classes. It cannot change the classes. It only applies rules based on the existing classes or other attributes. The moment you want to add/remove classes or other attributes, you're looking at JS, not CSS. I guess one needs to read the definition of DOM manipulation to be able to tell if something is or is not DOM manipulation.

Comment: Ok, I want to "enable/disable" different classes when different conditions occur.  That is what happens when you hover, focus or target an element.  It's not DOM manipulation.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't "enable/disable" classes using CSS. CSS is static. If and when a class/attribute/state exists on an element, the rule applies. If not, it doesn't. But, speaking about `state`, what you are after is possible by placing invisible checkboxes before each menu and making the entire menu a label for the checkbox. In CSS, you'd use something like `input:checked + .menu {/*display rule here*/}`. However, you'll run into trouble with the click events, as they'll be consumed by either menu link or label. Without `JS` I don't see how you could use a `click` event for two actions.

Comment: I added the solution I'm describing above to the answer, just for kicks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed the HTML tags not for semantics but for clarity. I find Nested lists easier to visualize if every other level is represented by `<dl>`, `<dt>`, `<dd>` list elements.
2. Used hidden radio inputs since it's the easiest way to maintain a 'state' (ex. 'on' and 'off') indefinitely using only CSS.
3. Targeting elements is done by pairing off groups of `<label>`s and `<input type="radio">`s.
4. Used the `visibility` property because it's ability to keep children elements of an element with `visibility: hidden` visible if said child had `visibility: visible` explicitly set.

I'm not sure what use it really is to remove the parent of a menu and wasn't sure if OP wanted the parent back or not. So the headings aren't really gone when the menu items are clicked, they are just invisible. If you want them back, just click the space above the lists.

**SNIPPET**

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.rad {
  display: none;
}
.rad + label,
dd {
  visibility: hidden;
}
dl:hover dd,
.rad:checked + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
  color: #fc2;
}
dd label:hover {
  background: #930;
  border: .5px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mainNav">
  <div class="drNav">
    <ul class="mainMenu">
      <li>
        <dl class="menuContent">
          <input id='rad0' class='rad' name='radA' type='radio' checked>
          <label for='rad0'>
            <dt class="menuHeader">HOME___</dt>
          </label>
          <dd>
            <label for='rad1'>
              <input id='rad1' class='rad' name='radA' type='radio'>Item1
            </label>

          </dd>
          <dd>
            <label for='rad2'>
              <input id='rad2' class='rad' name='radA' type='radio'>Item2
            </label>

          </dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li>
        <dl class="menuContent">
          <input id='rad3' class='rad' name='radB' type='radio' checked>
          <label for='rad3'>
            <dt class="menuHeader">CONTENT</dt>
          </label>
          <dd>
            <label for='rad4'>
              <input id='rad4' class='rad' name='radB' type='radio'>Item3
            </label>

          </dd>
          <dd>
            <label for='rad5'>
              <input id='rad5' class='rad' name='radB' type='radio'>Item4
            </label>

          </dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```